# Parameterized SQL in C# Application

Tags: c#, sql, parameterized-query

I'm building a SQL query, trying to make it safer by using a parameterized query. I've got the below, does this look ok or is there anything I can/need to change?

```
// Connection to SQL
string connectionString = "Data Source= PC\\SQL;Initial Catalog= Catalog;Integrated Security=False; User ID=; Password=";

// SQL Insert Command - Must Use The Below For Commands!
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
SqlCommand Insert = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO database (OS) VALUES (@ad)", connection);
Insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ad", adtb.text);

connection.Open();
Insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

I've left out certain details (db name etc).

Any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: your table is called database ?

Comment: you could put your connection in a using construct EX. using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{ }

Comment: Have you ever executed this and got error/output? If so , post those as well.

Comment: _does this look ok or is there anything I can/need to change_ definitily not a good way to ask a question.

Comment: No, the table isn't called database.

Comment: Soner Gonul, thank you for your helpful comment.

Comment: Read this -> http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Comment: Ger, thank you! I'll give that a try, thank you for posting something helpful, greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does it work? If yes, it is working. If no, show exact error messages or exceptions and we can try to help fix the problems.

Comment: `Brendan` I would do a quick GOOGLE Search on how to construct a INSERT SQL Command using Parameters in C# your Insert Command is not formatted correctly here is a simple / easy to read link 
[Inserting Data Into Database using C#](http://mrbool.com/inserting-data-into-sql-server-database-using-csharp-and-asp-net/25091)

Comment: I would name the `SQLCommand` cmd instead of `Insert` but this does also work ofcourse.

Comment: This would be better on Code Review site if there aren't any errors

Comment: There are no errors, sorry, should have made that clear at the time of posting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it like this:-

```
// Read this connection string from `Web.Config` file instead.
string connectionString = "Data Source= PC\\SQL;
   Initial Catalog= Catalog;Integrated Security=False; User ID=; Password=";
```

Can be written as follows to avoid re-compiling every time you change the connection strings:-

```
string connectionString  = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionString["YourKey"]
                                                  .ConnectionString;
```

Consider using `using` statement to dispose your valuable resources:

```
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using(SqlCommand Insert = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO database (OS) 
                                              VALUES (@ad)", connection))
{
    Insert.Parameters.Add("@ad", SqlDbType.NVarchar,10).Value = adtb.text;
    connection.Open();
    Insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Avoid using `AddWithValue`, Read [this](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Comment: Thank you for your help, As part of a select statement, using the same method as above, could I use for example 'Select * From Table Where UserName = @UN + '%''

Comment: And when specifying a `SqlDbType.NVarChar`, I would suggest to *always* also specify an **explicit length** for that ...

Comment: @marc_s - Thank You Marc, Have added that.

Comment: @brendan - You can but male sure you use `Parameterized query` like you did for insert.

Comment: Thank you Rahul, it would be using a Parameterized query, the only difference would be the + '%' after the @UN part.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly feel taking a risk to answer your question, but anyway..

First of all, `database` is a [reserved keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) in T-SQL. You should use it with square brackets like `[database]`. But as a better way, don't. Change it to *non-reserved* word which is meaningful for your.

Second, use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` instead of calling `.Dispose()` method manually..

Third, as a best practice, don't use `AddWithValue` method. It may generate unexpected results. Use [`.Add()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection.Add%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or it's overloads. Read: [Can we stop using `AddWithValue()` already](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)?

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using(SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [database] (OS) VALUES (@ad)";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ad", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 16).Value = adtb.text;
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: As I explained earlier, I've left parts out intentionally. 'Database' was simply inserted into the example as an example name for the database.

Comment: And when specifying a `SqlDbType.NVarChar`, I would suggest to *always* also specify an **explicit length** for that ...